# Relation of $\lVert \dot u \rVert_{W^1(\Omega)}$ to $ \lVert u \rVert_{W^1(\Omega)}$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am working with the space $W(\Omega) = H^1(\Omega)/\mathbb{R}$. I have the following definition and proposition:

1. Suppose that $\Omega$ is connected. The quotient space
   $$ W(\Omega) = H^1(\Omega)/ \mathbb{R}$$
   is defined as the space of classes of equivalence with respect to the relation 
   $$ u \simeq v \Longleftrightarrow u-v \text{ is a constant}, \quad \forall u,v \in H^1(\Omega).$$
   We denote by $\dot u$ the class of equivalence represented by $u$.
2. Suppose that $\Omega$ is connected. The following quantity:
   $$\lVert \dot{u} \rVert_{W(\Omega)} = \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad \forall u \in \dot{u}, \, \dot{u} \in W(\Omega),$$
   defines a norm on $W(\Omega)$ for which $W(\Omega)$ is a Banach space.
   Moreover, $W(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space for the scalar product
   $$ (v,w)_{W(\Omega)} = \sum_{i=1}^N \Bigg( \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}
    \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x_i}  \Bigg)_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad \forall v,w \in W(\Omega).$$

My question is: how can I relate  $\lVert \dot u \rVert_{W(\Omega)}$  to $ \lVert u \rVert_{W(\Omega)}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your previous question. (You should leave a comment if this happens, rather than asking a new question!) What is your definition of $|| u ||_{W^1(\Omega)}$?

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. I am using the book Introduction to Homogenization by Cioranescu, Damlamian, and Griso. They did not define there $\lVert u \rVert_{W(\Omega)}$ but they used it in the a priori estimate. The norm defined in the book is $\lVert \dot{u} \rVert_{W(\Omega)}$. Sorry there was a typo. I am considering the space $W(\Omega)$ not $W^1(\Omega)$. 
I'll keep in mind what you said about leaving comments. Thanks!

Comment: My best guess is that $|| u ||_{W(\Omega)}$ refers to $|| u ||_{H^1(\Omega)} = \left( || u ||_{L^2 (\Omega)}^2 + || \nabla u ||_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \right)^{\frac 1 2}$. This to me seems like the only thing that would make sense in the context of your previous question on math.SE, assuming that the motivation for your previous question is to prove existence of weak solutions to elliptic PDEs. I don't have your book I'm afraid, so what I'm saying is based on what I've learned from Evan's book.

Comment: Yes my goal is indeed to prove the existence of a weak solution of a PDE with a nonhomogeneous Neumann boundary condition. You think I can use the same norm for $W(\Omega)$? I will define the norm $\lVert u \rVert_{W(\Omega)}$ = $\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)}$? Also what is the title of Evan's book? Many thanks!

Comment: Well $|| . ||_{H^1(\Omega)}$ cannot be used as a norm on elements of $W(\Omega)$ because the value of $|| . ||_{H^1(\Omega)}$ depends on which representative you pick for the equivalence class. The answer I gave was really intended for Dirichlet boundary conditions, where $u$ is assumed to be in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ (the zero in the subscript symbolising that $u$ is in the closure of the space of functions with compact support).

Comment: If you're dealing with Neumann boundary conditions, then perhaps it would make more sense to simply define $|| u ||_{W(\Omega)}$ as $|| \nabla u ||_{L^2(\Omega)}$?

Comment: Can I simply define that norm (with an additional assumption that the mean value of $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ is zero so that the Poincare-Wirtinger Inequality becomes similar to Poincare inequality)?

Comment: This norm doesn't depend on your choice of representative of the equivalence class, i.e. $||  \nabla(u + c) ||_{L^2(\Omega)} = || \nabla u ||_{L^2 (\Omega)}$ for any constant $c$. Of course, you can always choose a representative of the equivalence class such that the mean value is zero, but I don't see how that is related to defining the norm.

Comment: http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/pde/Sobolev/embededness_cptness.pdf p.4

They have showed here that $\lVert u \rVert = \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ in $H^1_0$. I am not sure if I can follow their arguments so that I can define $\lVert u \rVert_{W(\Omega)}= \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$. They used Poincare inequality. In my case, I am not sure if I can use the Poincare Wirtinger inequality, with mean value equal to zero, so that it simply becomes Poincare inequality, and follow their arguments.

Comment: Yeah, those notes seem to deal with the Dirichlet case. They are very similar to how it's covered in Evans' PDEs book. So how you should proceed depends very much on whether you want to prove simply that $A(u,u) \geq \alpha || \nabla u ||_{L^2(\Omega)} = || \dot u ||_{W(\Omega)}$ (which you have already done) or whether you want to prove that $A(u,u) \geq \frac{\alpha}{C} || u ||_{H^1(\Omega)}$ where $u$ is a representative of the equivalence class with zero mean over $\Omega$ (which you can do by replacing Poincare with Poincare-Wirtinger).

Comment: Thanks Kenny for your helpful comments!

Comment: I hope you manage to resolve the issues! I've always been embarrassed about how little I know about Neumann boundary conditions. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega$ is bounded, connected and sufficiently regular (say $\partial \Omega$ Lipschitz continuous), then you have Poincare-Wirtinger Inequality 
$$\int_\Omega |u(x)-u_\Omega|^2dx\le c\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2dx,$$
where $u_\Omega$ is the average of $u$ over $\Omega$.
This gives you that
$$\inf_{d\in\mathbb{R}}\int_\Omega |u(x)-d|^2dx\le c\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2dx.$$ 
Hence in this case the two norms are equivalent.
However, if $\Omega$ is not regular (the typical example is called the room and corridors) then in general you do not have Poincare-Wirtinger and so the two norms are not equivalent.